# Getting error contains disallowed nested bundles" and "contains disallowed file 'Frameworks'" errors

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I'm developing an application which is using framework and this framework contains another framework , while deploying into app store I'm getting this error contains disallowed nested bundles" and "contains disallowed file 'Frameworks'" errors